# Could not retrieve the required installation files what to do?

Tags: system-installation

I get this message when I'm trying to install ubuntu from the start up help. Just rebooting and starting from the cd didn't work for me.

I'm refered to a log for this problem and I find the errors, but I have no idea what it all means:

```
01-25 18:33 INFO   root: === wubi 14.04 rev286 ===
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  root: Logfile is c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\wubi-14.04-rev286.log
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  root: sys.argv = ['main.pyo', '--exefile="D:\\wubi.exe"']
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: data_dir=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\data
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: 7z=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\bin\7z.exe
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: startup_folder=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Fetching basic info...
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: original_exe=D:\wubi.exe
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: platform=win32
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: osname=nt
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: language=en_US
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: encoding=cp1252
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: arch=amd64
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Parsing isolist=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\data\isolist.ini
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-i386
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-amd64
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-i386
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-amd64
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-amd64
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-amd64
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-i386
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-i386
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-amd64
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-i386
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-i386
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-amd64
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Fetching host info...
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: registry_key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows version=vista
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_version2=Windows 8.1
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_sp=None
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_build=9600
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: gmt=2
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: country=US
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: timezone=America/New_York
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_username=USER
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_full_name=USER
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_directory=C:\Users\USER
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language_code=1033
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language=English
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: processor_name=Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: bootloader=vista
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: system_drive=Drive(C: hd 187741.617188 mb free ntfs)
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(C: hd 187741.617188 mb free ntfs)
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(D: cd 0.0 mb free cdfs)
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(E: hd 867880.121094 mb free ntfs)
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(M: hd 30500.4921875 mb free fat32)
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: uninstaller_path=C:\ubuntu\uninstall-wubi.exe
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_target_dir=C:\ubuntu
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_distro_name=Ubuntu
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_id=67699721
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_layout=us
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_variant=
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: python locale=('en_US', 'cp1252')
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: locale=en_US.UTF-8
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: total_memory_mb=4095.99999905
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching ISOs on USB devices
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local CDs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   parsing info from str=Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS "Trusty Tahr" - Release amd64 (20140722.2)
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   parsed info={'name': 'Ubuntu', 'subversion': 'Release', 'version': '14.04.1', 'build': '20140722.2', 'codename': 'Trusty Tahr', 'arch': 'amd64'}
01-25 18:33 INFO   Distro: Found a valid CD for Ubuntu: D:\
01-25 18:33 INFO   root: Running the CD menu...
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: __init__...
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: on_init...
01-25 18:33 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
01-25 18:33 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
01-25 18:33 INFO   root: CD menu finished
01-25 18:33 INFO   root: Already installed, running the uninstaller...
01-25 18:33 INFO   root: Running the uninstaller...
01-25 18:33 INFO   CommonBackend: This is the uninstaller running
01-25 18:33 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
01-25 18:33 INFO   root: Received settings
01-25 18:33 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: # Running tasklist...
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running Remove bootloader entry...
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Could not find bcd id
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: undo_bootini C:
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: undo_configsys Drive(C: hd 187741.617188 mb free ntfs)
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: undo_bootini E:
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: undo_configsys Drive(E: hd 867880.121094 mb free ntfs)
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: undo_bootini M:
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: undo_configsys Drive(M: hd 30500.4921875 mb free fat32)
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished Remove bootloader entry
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running Remove target dir...
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Deleting C:\ubuntu
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished Remove target dir
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running Remove registry key...
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished Remove registry key
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
01-25 18:33 INFO   root: Almost finished uninstalling
01-25 18:33 INFO   root: Finished uninstallation
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Fetching basic info...
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: original_exe=D:\wubi.exe
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: platform=win32
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: osname=nt
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: arch=amd64
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Parsing isolist=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\data\isolist.ini
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-i386
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-amd64
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-i386
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-amd64
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-amd64
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-amd64
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-i386
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-i386
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-amd64
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-i386
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-i386
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-amd64
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Fetching host info...
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: registry_key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows version=vista
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_version2=Windows 8.1
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_sp=None
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_build=9600
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: gmt=2
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: country=US
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: timezone=America/New_York
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_username=USER
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_full_name=USER
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_directory=C:\Users\USER
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language_code=1033
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language=English
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: processor_name=Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: bootloader=vista
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: system_drive=Drive(C: hd 188725.191406 mb free ntfs)
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(C: hd 188725.191406 mb free ntfs)
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(D: cd 0.0 mb free cdfs)
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(E: hd 867880.121094 mb free ntfs)
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(M: hd 30500.4921875 mb free fat32)
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: uninstaller_path=None
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_target_dir=None
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_distro_name=None
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_id=67699721
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_layout=us
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_variant=
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: total_memory_mb=4095.99999905
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching ISOs on USB devices
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local CDs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
01-25 18:33 INFO   Distro: Found a valid CD for Ubuntu: D:\
01-25 18:33 INFO   root: Running the CD boot helper...
01-25 18:33 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
01-25 18:33 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
01-25 18:33 INFO   root: CD boot helper confirmed
01-25 18:33 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: # Running tasklist...
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running select_target_dir...
01-25 18:33 INFO   WindowsBackend: Installing into C:\ubuntu
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished select_target_dir
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running create_dir_structure...
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\disks
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\install
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\install\boot
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\disks\boot
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\disks\boot\grub
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\install\boot\grub
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished create_dir_structure
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running uncompress_target_dir...
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished uncompress_target_dir
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running create_uninstaller...
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying uninstaller D:\wubi.exe -> C:\ubuntu\uninstall-wubi.exe
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi UninstallString C:\ubuntu\uninstall-wubi.exe
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi InstallationDir C:\ubuntu
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi DisplayName Ubuntu
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi DisplayIcon C:\ubuntu\Ubuntu.ico
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi DisplayVersion 14.04-rev286
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi Publisher Ubuntu
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi URLInfoAbout http:/www.ubuntu.com
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi HelpLink http:/www.ubuntu.com/support
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished create_uninstaller
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running copy_installation_files...
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\data\custom-installation -> C:\ubuntu\install\custom-installation
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\winboot -> C:\ubuntu\winboot
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pylC830.tmp\data\images\Ubuntu.ico -> C:\ubuntu\Ubuntu.ico
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished copy_installation_files
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running use_cd...
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: New task copy_file
01-25 18:33 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running copy_file...
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished copy_file
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  TaskList: New task check_iso
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running check_iso...
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Checking C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  Distro:   checking Ubuntu ISO C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  WindowsBackend:   extracting .disk\info from C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  Distro:   parsing info from str=Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS "Trusty Tahr" - Release amd64 (20140722.2)
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  Distro:   parsed info={'name': 'Ubuntu', 'subversion': 'Release', 'version': '14.04.1', 'build': '20140722.2', 'codename': 'Trusty Tahr', 'arch': 'amd64'}
01-25 18:35 INFO   Distro: Found a valid iso for Ubuntu: C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  TaskList: New task get_metalink
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Running get_metalink...
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  downloader: downloading http:/releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink > C:\ubuntu\install
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  downloader: Download start filename=C:\ubuntu\install\ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink, url=http:/releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink, basename=ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink, length=45848, text=None
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  downloader: download finished (read 45848 bytes)
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  downloader: downloading http:/releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/MD5SUMS-metalink > C:\ubuntu\install
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  downloader: Download start filename=C:\ubuntu\install\MD5SUMS-metalink, url=http:/releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/MD5SUMS-metalink, basename=MD5SUMS-metalink, length=560, text=None
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  downloader: download finished (read 560 bytes)
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  downloader: downloading http:/releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/MD5SUMS-metalink.gpg > C:\ubuntu\install
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  downloader: Download start filename=C:\ubuntu\install\MD5SUMS-metalink.gpg, url=http:/releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/MD5SUMS-metalink.gpg, basename=MD5SUMS-metalink.gpg, length=198, text=None
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  downloader: download finished (read 198 bytes)
01-25 18:35 INFO   saplog: Verified a signature from ID:'46181433FBB75451'.
01-25 18:35 INFO   saplog: Checking block bindings..
01-25 18:35 INFO   saplog: Key verified successfully.
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  CommonBackend: metalink md5sums:
a6e180b2c31d7b1eea24679b8205f01c *ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink
d2c9e1eb6bc9b1ba67c06fdd4fd0347e *ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.metalink
b87f557d59555df5f4577d2700292f1f *ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.metalink
63bf3b3b0eab70e6f8291605aea3d924 *ubuntu-14.04-server-i386.metalink
d1cbb30d6eab71cca40f3df717dc210c *ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.metalink
3ae778859e3e1f830bc31d9d36c74d21 *ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.metalink
3bb29eaa4d905b0e6edac12b5d7d3d91 *ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.metalink
38cd72646a2299b401fe7de19c54fa5b *ubuntu-14.04.1-server-i386.metalink

01-25 18:35 ERROR  CommonBackend: The md5 of the metalink does match
01-25 18:35 ERROR  CommonBackend: Cannot authenticate the metalink file, it might be corrupt
None
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Finished get_metalink
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  TaskList: New task get_file_md5
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Running get_file_md5...
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Finished get_file_md5
01-25 18:35 ERROR  CommonBackend: Invalid md5 for ISO C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso (dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153 != 119cb63b48c9a18f31f417f09655efbd)
None
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished check_iso
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished use_cd
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running extract_kernel...
01-25 18:35 ERROR  TaskList: Could not retrieve the required installation files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 618, in extract_kernel
Exception: Could not retrieve the required installation files
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
01-25 18:35 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
01-25 18:35 ERROR  root: Could not retrieve the required installation files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 130, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 205, in run_cd_menu
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 122, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 228, in run_cd_boot
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 618, in extract_kernel
Exception: Could not retrieve the required installation files
```

help me please

Comment: "01-25 18:35 ERROR  CommonBackend: The md5 of the metalink does match". Mind though: WUBI does NOT work with Windows 8.1.